# Exclude some, not all, user profiles from search engine results

Tags: users

Is there a way to let users choose if they want their user profile to be excluded from external search engine results? Any modules or hooks known?

It should be based on the de/selection of a boolean field "Display my user profile in search engine results".

Answer (score 2):

There is and there is not, there are two sides of that question.

Bad side is - external search engines are just that: external. You can send them suggestion but you cannot make sure they respect them.

Good side is - you can create a field, and if it's checked output: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` Some search engines, [including Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag), [Bing](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/block-urls-from-bing-264e560a) and apparently Yahoo! *(can't find a link for that one)*, will respect that.

Comment: This seems like the correct thing to do. Do you know if it is achievable with Rules module? Otherwise I wouldn't know how to add `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` to my page template without writing a custom module from scratch.

Comment: To make sure that search engines don't pick up those specific user profiles, I could also set their access permissions to "authenticated users only". But obviously this is even more than what I want.

Comment: @deinqwertz [template_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile/7) is what you need. Not a module, just a function in your template. You would need to set a variable there, and then if it's set  in html.tpl.php output proper part. Or something like that, details about changing template parts based on fields deserve their own question.